# good practice to structure designers files in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Generally designers design static cshtml files after slicing PSDs before developers can use them to create dynamic pages. How these static html files should be structured in an application, such that:

- They have their repository versions
- Can share common JQuery/CSS/Images in solution used by other actual coded pages
- Doesn't goes to production upon deployments

One good approach is:

```
Project
|_Area
   |_Design
     |_Controllers
       |_ ModuleA Controller (Has 1 controller with viewname argument and renders it)
       |_ ModuleB Controller (Has 1 controller with viewname argument and renders it)
     |_Views
       |_ModuleA
         |_StaticScreen1.cshtml
         |_StaticScreen2.cshtml
         |_StaticScreen3.cshtml
       |_ModuleB
         |_StaticScreenA.cshtml
```

This approach works good for 1st 2 points and is easy for designer too as they just need to keep adding screens in respective view folder. On a downside, this gets deployed to production too. Please suggest a better approach.

Comment: Just providing information on what I'm finally doing: http://discusscode.blogspot.in/2012/06/managing-raw-html-and-razor-code-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Click on each file you don't want and look at the Properties.

Change 'Build Action' to 'None'

When you Publish, the items with Build Action:None will not be included.